# Как передать значение value из поля input в controller.php

Tags: php, массивы, post, get

Здравствуйте!

Принимаю goods_id товара по клику на ссылку:

```
<a href="<?=PATH?>addtocart/<?=$goods['goods_id']?>">В корзину</a>
```

и передаю goods_id в **controller.php**. Затем из **controller.php** значение goods_id летит в **model.php** и там реализуется функция показа сколько товара в корзине.

Открываю сессию в **controller.php**:

```
session_start();
```

затем в **controller.php** прописываю:

```
 case('addtocart'):
    $goods_id = abs((int)$_GET['goods_id']);
    addtocart($goods_id);
 break;
```

затем в **model.php** прописываю:

```
function addtocart($goods_id, $qty = 1){
   if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$goods_id])){
    // если в массиве cart уже есть добавляемый товар
       $_SESSION['cart'][$goods_id]['qty'] += $qty;
       return $_SESSION['cart'];
   }else{
    // если товар кладется в корзину впервые
       $_SESSION['cart'][$goods_id]['qty'] = $qty;
       return $_SESSION['cart'];
   }
}
```

Распечатываю массив:

```
<?php print_arr($_SESSION) ?>
```

И выводится:

```
Array
(
    [cart] => Array
        (
            [6] => Array
                (
                    [qty] => 1              
                )
        )
)
```

6 - это goods_id товара, а qty - это количество товара (т.е. кликнул один раз на ссылку = 1, кликну два раза на ссылку - будет 2 товара в корзине).

Все работает отлично. Но как мне сделать так, чтобы пользователь смог добавлять произвольное кол-во товара. Сейчас по клику на ссылку добавится столько товара, сколько пользователь кликнул на ссылку.

Понял одно, что необходимо добавить поле **input**.
Пробовал его передавать GET параметром в **controller.php**  - не получается.
Например:

```
<input type="text" value="1" name="kol" />
<a href="<?=PATH?>addtocart/<?=$goods['goods_id']?>">В корзину</a>
```

в **controller.php**:

```
case('addtocart'):
   $goods_id = abs((int)$_GET['goods_id']); 
   $kolvo = $_GET['kol'];
   addtocart($goods_id, $kolvo);
 break;
```

в **model.php** прописываю:

```
function addtocart($goods_id, $kolvo = 1){
   if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$goods_id])){
    // если в массиве cart уже есть добавляемый товар
       $_SESSION['cart'][$goods_id]['qty'] += $kolvo;
       return $_SESSION['cart'];
   }else{
    // если товар кладется в корзину впервые
       $_SESSION['cart'][$goods_id]['qty'] = $kolvo;
       return $_SESSION['cart'];
   }
}
```

Но ничего не работает. Вот, что выводит сессионный массив по клику на ссылку один раз:

```
Array
(
    [cart] => Array
        (
            [6] => Array
                (
                    [qty] =>               
                )
        )
)
```

по клику больше одного раза и более:

```
Array
(
    [cart] => Array
        (
            [6] => Array
                (
                    [qty] => 0              
                )
        )
)
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. Возможно что-то не правильно с GET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А с чего в GET что-то будет?
Нужно input и ссылку обернуть в form, используя метод POST.
id товара упакуйте в input hidden.
Кнопку c типом submit.
Примерно вот так

```
<form action="<?=PATH?>addtocart" method="POST">
    <input type="text" value="1" name="kol" />
    <input type="hidden" name="goods_id" value="<?=$goods['goods_id']?>" />
    <button type="submit">В корзину</button>
</form>
```

В controller.php вместо $_GET следует использовать $_POST

Comment: Пробовал, не работает. покажите, пожалуйста на примере моего кода.

Comment: добавил код в ответ

Comment: Спасибо и Вам большое! Только необходимо было полностью указать в обработчике ссылку, вместе c  `<?=$goods['goods_id']?>"`

Comment: Для чего это надо было указать в ссылке? вы через $_GET получаете данные?

Comment: Все уже решено! Спасибо! Почитайте комментарии к другому ответу. id товара необходимо тоже передавать.. иначе не понятно какой товар записывается в сессию и просто кидает на ссылку  `<?=PATH?>addtocart`

Comment: Понятно что решено :) Но не понятно зачем id товара передавать в ссылке. Покажите код где идет обработка.

Comment: Если честно сам не понимаю пока, но без id не работает.  Мне необходимо для каждой новой страницы на сайте в controller.php создать case. Например чтобы перейти по ссылке www.test.ru/one - необходимо создать `case('one'):` и затем там прописывать уже выполняемые операции... В случае же с корзиной, если указывать без id товара, то будет перенаправлять на страницу www.test.ru/addtocart. Поэтому необходимо указать конкретный id товара, так работает. Код написан выше весь. Ни чего не скрываю)

Comment: Потому что id товара ты получаешь через GET поэтому его и нужно писать в ссылке. Форма у тебя метод POST. Чтобы получить id товара из инпута нужно использовать $_POST['goods_id']

Comment: Это я уже давно понял.  Вроде бы вы в своем вопросе имели другое совсем - Зачем необходимо было полностью в обработчике прописать ссылку.  По сути, если бы это была например простая страница, где пользователь регистрируется, вообще не нужно было бы писать что-то в обработчике action, как сейчас у меня это сделано.

Answer (score 1):

Первое что очень заметно - вы вставили input  + link ?! и как это будет работать?

```
<input type="text" value="1" name="kol" />
<a href="<?=PATH?>addtocart/<?=$goods['goods_id']?>">В корзину</a>
```

"Понял одно, что необходимо добавить поле input. Пробовал его передавать GET параметром в controller.php - не получается." -- да верно необходимо отправлять данные из input. однако я не вижу в вашем примере форму для отправки... попробуйте так:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Добавить в корзину">
<input type="text" value="1" name="kol" />
<input type="hidden" value="<?=$goods['goods_id']?>" name="goods_id" />
<input type="hidden" name="task" value="{ваш класс}.addtocart{ваша функция в контроллере}" />

</form>
```

в controller.php

```
$goods_id = abs((int)$_POST['goods_id']); 
   $kolvo = $_POST['kol'];
   addtocart($goods_id, $kolvo);
```

я попробовал описать общую логику - остальное вы экспериментируйте

Comment: $_GET не прокатит, т.к. метод у формы POST

Comment: да конечно )) я просто по инерции скопировал ) поменяю

Comment: @Arsen Спасибо! Скажите, пожалуйста, для чего нужен input с именем task ?

Comment: в input name="task" вы можете вставить имя класса(контроллера) и после точки пишите имя функции которая получит данный запрос, и в данной функции вы можете получить инфу которая отправленна с формы, при использовании OOP такой метод более оптимальный и красивый (ИМХО) )). Но конечно вы можете использовать другую конструкцию, всё зависит от того какой фреймворк используете и т.д....

Comment: @Arsen Спасибо большое:) Но у меня не на OOP. Немного по другому. Буду знать на будущее.

Comment: думаю вы должны использовать OOP (объектно-ориентированное программирование)  у вас же используется MVC архитектура.... Model->View->Controller )) куда без ООП

Comment: @Arsen В OOP используется множество контроллеров и моделей насколько я знаю. У меня же описано все в одном контроллере и одной модели. Все намного проще. На OOP я хотел переписать сайт в одно время, но что-то так и не взялся. Возможно и у меня можно назвать OOP, но написано не как на OOP :)))

Comment: @Arsen а также пришлось прописать в обработчик - `action="<?=PATH?>addtocart/<?=$goods['goods_id']?>"`. Иначе не работало.

Comment: да в action тоже можно)